# How do I write regular expression in Java that takes into account the context of the string I'm looking for?

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse a HTML code and create objects from their text representation in table. I have several columns and I want to save context of certain columns on every row. 
Now, I have the HTML code and I understand I should use Pattern and Matcher to get those strings, but I don't know how to write required regular expression.

This is a row I will be parsing:

`<tr><td><a href="delirium.htm">Delirium</a></td><td>65...</tr>`

So, I want to extract Delirium from that string. How do I write regular expression that sais

get me the string that is between the string `htm">` and `</a></td>`

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common question on SO and the answer is always the same: regular expressions are a poor and limited tool for parsing HTML because HTML is not a regular language.

You should be using [an HTML parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers), for example [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

If you're curious what I mean by "regular language", have a look at [JMD, Markdown and a Brief Overview of Parsing and Compilers](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/jmd-markdown-and-brief-overview-of.html). Basically a regular expression is a DFA (deterministic finite automaton or deterministic finite state machine). HTML requires a PDA (pushdown automaton) to parse. A PDA is a DFA with a stack. It's how it handles recursive elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. So is search function which I fail to use lately ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
htm">(.+)</a></td>
```

Searches for any character (that's the `.+` bit) that is between `htm">` and `</a></td>` and return what's in between to use with Pattern.matcher() (which is why there are brackets around `.+` )

http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html